# Memory Usage Really high in ARC

Tags: iphone, memory, automatic-ref-counting

In my app I have noticed that it goes very slow when switching between tabs. Further investigation showed that in my memory usage test my app was over 70mb in 5 minutes of testing. My native email app was only using 40mb. This cannot happen

I am using ARC and what I thought was that if I use something like

```
@property(nonatomic, strong)NSString *string;
```

ARC will dealloc this automatically. It doesn't seem to be doing that at all.

What I would like to know is if I can reduce my memory by using `dealloc` in my code (when I switched to ARC it deleted all my `dealloc` methods) or if there is another way to speed up my  app.

To give you more information on what the app does here is a list of key points:

-Gets mail messages from webservice along with pdfs

-Stores arrays to check if messages have been read, deleted, or unread

-Mail tab checks for new messages from the webservice everytime someone clicks on the tab

-Same check for pdf files

Any information will help me a lot.

Thanks

**EDIT**

Here are pictures of the leaks I have. Its a lot.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to find out what the reason is for this high memory usage is using the `Instruments` tool and more specifically the `Leaks` tool.

You can find more info on the Apple developer site [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/FindingLeaks.html).

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the help. Take a look at the edit in my question. I have added the leaks.

Comment: May i suggest to take a look at the WWDC 2010 videos: Session 311 - Advanced Memory Analysis with Instruments. That should help you to make sense of the Instruments interface to find the code causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar to ARC but I suppose it may slow a bit your app. Why? Think: ARC will automatically do your "release" job, against your manual release. Suppose you have a 30 lines method, and in the first line you create an object, then in the third line you don't need it anymore and you manually release it. While ARC will wait until the end of the method to realize that your object is not needed anymore. Now suppose you make a plenty of allocations in your method, and ARC will keep them all until the end of the method is reached. Releasing manually is faster IMHO.